# Коллбэк в слайдере

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

На [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/slider_handmade/) есть слайдер (смотрите только в `firefox`). В скрипте инициализации установлен эффект `fade`. но при прокрутке слайда функция `hideEffect()`, которая отвечает за реализацию эффекта не действует. то есть смена слайда происходит мгновенно. Причина мне не понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Привет!

До конца не стал разбираться, но нашел ошибку. Смотри: http://jsfiddle.net/RcKam/

Строка 83 в JS окне, а у тебя вот так:

```
function shift(effectSpeed = 0, hideEffect = false){
    slides_wrap.stop(true, true).animate({
        marginLeft: -position * options.slide_width
    }, hideEffect);         
}
```

Comment: привет. ответил здесь
http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/a.txt
 так как этот сайт не разрешает постить много букв